# Mathematically detailed book on regression

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, references

I'm finishing *All of Statistics*, by Larry Wasserman, which is very good to get a broad picture of Statistics. Now I would like a specific book that deals with regression, but I would like a mathematically detailed book, one that proves the results and that just not simply shows the formulas.

Comment: [Reference requests are considered on-topic, even if answers will be somewhat opinion-based.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1629/1352)

Answer (score 3):

> I would like a mathematically detailed book, one that proves the
>   results and that just not simply shows the formulas.

You might want to check [Seber's book: Linear Regression Analysis.](http://amzn.to/2BppKh1) It's more statistically oriented and has basically all main derivations in the text itself.

Answer (score 2):

[Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Pannel Data](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540262393)
 from Jeffrey M. Woolridge is one of the most famous book about regression and econometrics. It covers cross-section and pannel data while you should read an additional book about time series, e.g. [New Introduction to Multiple Time Series](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540262393) by Luetkepohl.

Answer (score 1):

The most detailed book on regression I’ve ever read is *”Econometric methods with applications in business and economics”* by Heij et al.

Don’t let the title mislead you, the book is very focused on details and demonstrations.

For multivariate models go for the “*New introduction to multiple time series*” from Lutkepohl.
Again, don’t let the title fool you... it is a lot more than an introduction.